# Can Aurelia's "repeat.for" be used with "view-model.ref"

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a `repeat.for` on a custom element in my view (giving me a list if UI elements):

```html
<box repeat.for="box of boxes" box.bind="box"></box>
```

I would like my view-model to have a list of the of the custom element's view-models (So I can call validate methods on each of the items in my list.)

I tried this:

```html
<div repeat.for="box of boxes">
    <box box.bind="box" view-model.ref="boxViewModels[${$index}]"></box>
</div>
```

But the `boxViewModels` property does not get anything added to the array.
I even tried to see if it would bind at all inside of the `repeat.for`:

```html
<div repeat.for="box of boxes">
    <box box.bind="box" view-model.ref="boxViewModelTesting"></box>
</div>
```

But after I created a few instances, `boxViewModelTesting` is `undefined`.

Makes me wonder if `view-model.ref` just will not work inside a `repeat.for`.

**Is there any way to get the references of view-models of custom attributes created with a 'repeat.for'?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a scenario that's part of the test suite.  Should look something like this:

```js
export class Foo {
  boxElements = [];
  boxViewModels = [];
  boxViews = [];
  boxControllers = [];
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div repeat.for="box of boxes">
    <box ref="boxElements[$index]"
         view-model.ref="boxViewModels[$index]"
         view.ref="boxViews[$index]"     
         controller.ref="boxControllers[$index]">
    </box>
  </div>
</template>
```

[Tests](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/blob/master/test/name-expression.spec.js)

**You must update to the 3/1/2016 version of Aurelia to use this**
http://blog.durandal.io/2016/03/01/aurelia-early-march-2016-update/

Comment: Are there recent changes to this functionality? This does not work in my app, but it does work in my Gist Run (https://gist.run/?id=30f77471ffeee12863a5).  My version is about a month old.

Comment: sorry! I assumed you were updated to the 3/1/2016 set of releases  You must update to use this feature.

Comment: Is there a jspm/npm command that will update me to that version?  I tried going to the latest version, and it does not work for me.  I would like to try using the version that is packaged in your gist so I know my code is the only difference.